# After using Pub Build - Minified on the pubspec.yaml of the order game, the board of the game does not appear in Chrome

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart2js

## dart2js problem

After using Pub Build - Minified on the pubspec.yaml of the [order](https://github.com/dzenanr/order) game,
the board of the game does not appear in Chrome.

The [boarding](https://github.com/dzenanr/boarding) package uses enums and mixins.

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: order
version: 0.2.7
author: Dzenan Ridjanovic <dzenanr@gmail.com>
description: An example from boarding.
homepage: https://github.com/dzenanr/boarding
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
documentation: http://goo.gl/kXlDOJ
dependencies:
  boarding: any
  browser: any
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    minify: true
    terse: true
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-enum]

Loading source assets...
Building order...
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling order|web/index.dart...
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:10.139580 to compile order|web/index.dart.
Built 7 files to "build".
```

There are no errors in Dart Editor nor Chrome.

Comment: I guess you have tried without `--enable-enums`. This shouldn't be needed in 1.9. Did you load the file from file URL or using some web server?

Comment: The same problem without commandLineOptions: [--enable-enum] in pubspec.yaml. I just double-clicked the html file (from file URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line below the `index.dart` script tag in `index.html`

```dart
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought it was there. Shame on me. I have lost so much time already on this one. Thank you so much Gunter.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem please accept it to mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark below the up- down-vote button.